# See which email addresses in G Suite have forwarding enabled and to where

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have a G Suite account with a few hundred accounts. I'd like to see which of these accounts if forwarding emails.

Like recently it was discovered that one employee was forwarding all their work emails to their personal account. I want to see if anyone else is doing that but there's not an easy way that I know of to make this determination.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Idea: [Disable automatic forwarding | Google Workspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2491924?hl=en)